# Swift - Animation not working when switch view and back

Tags: swift, animation, label

I notice that when I switch to another view and then back to the main view, my blinking animation stopped working. A tap brings it to another view and a button brings it back to the main view. Here is my code:

For blinking animation:

```
import Foundation
```

import UIKit

extension UILabel {

```
func startBlink() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8,
                   delay:0.0,
                   options:[.autoreverse, .repeat],
                   animations: {
                    self.alpha = 0

    }, completion: nil)
}

func stopBlink() {
    alpha = 1
    layer.removeAllAnimations()
}
```

}

Action for button to bring the it back to main screen:

```
@IBAction func mainMenuTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "EndToMain", sender: self)

}
```

Main view code that start the blinking animation:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tapToPlayLabel: UILabel!




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    tapToPlayLabel.startBlink()

}
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Put a break point on that startBlick function. Is it called when you segue to main controller?

Comment: No, it is not called when segue to main controller, it is called when the view loads. So when it switch back to the main controller it will be called since the viewed will have to load.

Comment: you want to animate button overtime the view is displayed ? if yes , just call your animating coding ViewDidAppear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the iOS `UIView` lifecycle to understand when which methods are called.

Take `tapToPlayLabel.startBlink()` out of viewDidLoad and put it into either `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` like this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    tapToPlayLabel.startBlink()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times UIView animation custom methods won't work when switching back to the original view. To make that work you need to assign some initial values related to that Custom animation.

Here is the example:

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewDidAppear(animated)
     self.tapToPlayLabel.alpa = 20
     self.tapToPlayLabel.layoutIfNeeded()
     self.tapToPlayLabel.startBlink()
}
```